# Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I installed everything that was needed for installing Django with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
pip install Django
pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /home/ion/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

And I tried to install with

```
pip3 install Django
pip3 --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

But when I run

```
django-admin --version
Cannot find installed version of python-django or python3-django.
```

I tried again to install django:

```
pip install Django==2.2.7
Requirement already satisfied: Django==2.2.7 in /home/ion/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.2.7)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /home/ion/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Django==2.2.7) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /home/ion/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Django==2.2.7) (2019.1)
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your default python interpreter is not 3.6, run this:

```
python3.6 -m pip install Django==2.2.7
```

And see if now you can `django-admin`.

Alternatively, try installing `python3-django` with apt-get.

Comment: installing with apt-get worked, but do you know why it didn't work with pip?

Comment: First you need to decide whether or not you'll need both versions of python 3 installed. Then, I'd suggest using virtualenv (like suggested in the answer below mine) or another type of environment switcher for multiple python interpreters. Having multiple versions is fine, as long as you know what you're doing and where to start checking whether or not you're running things in one interpreter or the other.

Comment: Because you see, you did `pip install`, then `pip3 install`, those might be using different interpreters.

Comment: I see, but here is the thing, I have anaconda installed on my laptop and with anaconda python 3.7
when I write conda list I see there python 3.7 but when I use pip list I can't see python 3.6 there, I am confused with conda and pip, I can't remember how I installed conda and for what.

Comment: Well, I guess that is now a problem for a different question and answer, as the OP django problem is now answered and solved. You might try again in a new question, to see how to sanitize your python environment. Thanks in advance for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 0):

make virtualenv with python3

first install python env by using command

```
sudo apt-get python3-virtualenv
```

then make virtual env by command

```
virtualenv --python=python3 django
```

then activate virtualenv by

```
source django/bin/activate
```

after that install django by

```
pip install django
```

Engoy ^_^;